# How to check if it's somebody's birthday in JS (with time zone)?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, timezone, date-fns

Earlier I asked about the concepts of storing birth dates and notifying users, after looking at some libraries I decided to go for date-fns and date-fns-tz, I figured I can store dates like this:

```js
import { utcToZonedTime, zonedTimeToUtc } from "date-fns-tz";

// Picked by user
const timeZone = "America/Los_Angeles";
const birthDate = "03-11";

const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(`2000-${birthDate} 00:00:00`, timeZone);

// Stored in database
console.log(utcDate.toISOString(), timeZone);
```

I am still missing the concept because I am stuck at the part where I check if it's somebody's birthday regardless of where my server is hosted, let's say I run a cron job at `0 0 * * *`, how would I know which people to message? I accept either a postgres or JavaScript solution (or combined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make the PostgreSQL query like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE
     DATE_PART('day', DOB) = date_part('day', CURRENT_DATE)
AND
     DATE_PART('month', DOB) = date_part('month', CURRENT_DATE)
AND
     cast(DOB as time) >= localtime;
```

where DOB is the birthdate stored.

---

Another solution which will acount for **leap years** as well

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
EXTRACT(YEARS FROM age(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DOB)) > user_age;
```

age is an inbuilt function which takes cares of the `leap years` as well,
we can store the user_age of the user and update when it changes.

Comment: Thank you, but if this is it, isn't working with time zones completely useless?

Comment: added the time check too

Comment: I am trying to think of what’s happening, I can safely store as iso string like in my question and then use this query and Postgres will compare the timezone against utc/ local time? I am worried there are cases where the message will be sent one day too early or too late since I’m storing the time as 00:00:00 and the year defaults to 2020 and my cron job runs at the same time (00:00), I think leap years can be a problem too

Comment: the message will never be sent early due to this condition `cast(DOB as time) >= localtime`, and too late depends at what frequency your cron runs

Comment: It will run once every beginning of a new day, what about leap years, is it something I can handle in the query or should I account for that before storing to the db?

Comment: I have added another solution which will account for leap years as well

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a nice solution, however in this case the users age is not stored because of privacy, that’s why I fallback to year 2000

Comment: You don't have to store the actual age, instead, you can store the age starting from the `2000` year, `user_age` is just needed to check if the new age is greater than the previous value

Comment: I see, so basically it’s not useful to store the preferred time zone in the db like Europe/Amsterdam?